# Wordpress WP_User_Query ignores the `meta_query` when called from an Ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax function that runs the following `WP_User_Query`:

```
        $args2 = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'gender' => array(
                        'key'     => 'gender',
                        'value'   => 'female',
                         'compare' => '='
                    )
                    ),
                    'number' => 10
         );
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args2 );
```

The query is returning unfiltered results, basically ignoring the `meta_query`. It works fine if I run it from `functions.php` or from a template file, but not from `ajax`. Any idea why?

This is the `request` string when it works:

```
                SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.ID
                FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
                )
                WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
                ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'gender' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'female' )
                )
                ORDER BY user_login ASC
                LIMIT 0, 10
```

And this is the one from the ajax function:

```
                SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.ID
                FROM wp_users
                WHERE 1=1
                ORDER BY user_login ASC
                LIMIT 0, 10
```

My query function in `functions.php`

```
function export_users_function_test() {
    $args = array(
        'number' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'employee',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'gender',
                'value' => 'female',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'member',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );
     $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    return $user_query;
}
```

My ajax function the calls the query function. The goal is to generate a CSV file with the results:

```
    public function export_users_function() {
        $params = $_POST['params'] ?: null;
         $query = export_users_function_test() ?: null;
        $users = $query ? $query->results : null;

        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
      
        $header = '"Email",';

        while(have_rows('file_columns', 'option') ): the_row();
          $header .= '"' . get_sub_field('column_name') . '",';
        endwhile;
        $header .=  "\r\n";
        if ($users) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $header .= '"' . $user->user_email . '",';
                while(have_rows('file_columns', 'option') ): the_row();
                $header .= '"' . get_user_meta( $user->ID, get_sub_field('user_meta_key'), true) . '",';
              endwhile;
              $header .=  "\r\n";
            }
        }
        echo wp_send_json($header);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) your syntax isnt valid.

If you are just querying one meta key & value then use the simplified version. `meta_query` ideally should be used for multiple queries or more complex ones.

```
$args2 = array(
    'meta_key' => 'gender',
    'meta_value' => 'female',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'number' => 10
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args2 );
```

Comment: I see your point, but my `meta_query` still gets ignored if I use more keys than one. Besides, the query works if I run the function from a template page for example. It just doesn't work from ajax. I also  tried leaving the function in `functions.php` and calling it from my ajax function, but got the same result.

Comment: are you getting results printed? `$results = $user_query->get_results();`

Comment: Yes, when I run the query I get different results depending on where I'm running it from. I get the correct results if I call the function from a template file, but the wrong, unfiltered results if I call it from my ajax function.

Comment: can you post your full ajax function?

Comment: I've added the functions to question above.

Comment: and your ajax function works well other than the query?

Comment: Yes, I get the results which I then pass to JS to generate the CSV file.